# dynamic output for ndgrid in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dynamic

I'd like to generate indices for an n-dimensional array with *ndgrid*.  Since the dimension may change, is there a way to wrap ndgrid so that the number of outputs for ndgrid is dynamic? Say for example, I want the *output* for a 2 dimension array to be:

```
 [output{1} output{2}]=ndgrid(1:5)
```

and the *output* for a 3 dimension array to be:

```
 [output{1} output{2} output{3}]=ndgrid(1:5)
```

so on and so forth...

Comment: You could always do it using eval and creating a string like "[output{1} output{2}...]" in a loop. But I imagine there is a cleaner way.

Comment: How about `[output{1:n}] = ndgrid(1:5);`?

Comment: @H.Muster: Why don't you make an answer out of this? It should resolve the question, I think.

Comment: @quazgar: It's just an one-liner that fits perfectly in a comment line. Nevertheless, feel free to use it and create an own answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want different sizes for the different dimensions, you might want to consider something like:
[creating adjacency matrix](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab_code/sparse_adj_matrix.m).
The relevant part is:

```
ndim = numel(sz);
I=cell(ndim,1);
% construct the neighborhood
for di=1:ndim
    I{di}=1:sz(di);
end
[I{1:ndim}]=ndgrid(I{:});
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using `I{1:ndim}` instead of `I{:}`?

Comment: @SimonePalazzo I'm not sure, but I think you need to define how many outputs you expect from `ndgrid`. You can try the other way and see what you get...